# Which of the Artificial Spirits creates the 4th Sakura Branch?

Tags: otome-yokai-zakuro

In *Otome Yōkai Zakuro*, when Zakuro, Susukihotaru, Bonbori and Hozuki enter a fight, the Artificial Spirits Mamezo, Sakura and Kiri pull out sakura branches to give to the girls. Susukihotaru, Bonbori and Hozuki just produce more sakura petals while Zakuro's turns into a knife.

However there's only 3 artificial spirits and we see each of them pull out one branch but there are 4 branches in total, who's pulling out a second?